# How to fix error "nonblocking pool is initialized"

Tags: ubuntu-16.04

I have Ubuntu 16.04. host server and there are three VM's installed over KVM.
Today in the morning host server has left without disk space and two of VM's were paused automatically by system.

One of them is now working ok but second one stucks at

**usbhid: USB HID core driver**u

**unonblocking pool is initialized**

I have tried to export qcow2 and import, create new machine and import, restart host machine but nothing from that helped 
me.

Is there anything I can try to do?

Here is image where you can see first error and second with pool comes a little bit latter.
[image]

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

```
virsh console myserver
fsck /dev/mapper/myserver--vg-root
```

Errors were fixed and I was able to run VM again.